# React Link - If location matches passed in Route, apply a class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have this general component, that calls SidebarLink:

```
<SidebarGroup>
  <SidebarLink>
    <Link to={routes.example1.path}>example1</Link>
  </SidebarLink>
  <SidebarLink>
    <Link to={routes.example2.path}>example2</Link>
  </SidebarLink>
</SidebarGroup>
```

SidebarLink is written like this:

```
const SidebarLink = ({ children }) => (
  <li className={styles.sidebarLink}>
    {children}
  </li>
);
```

With the following styles (showing only those related to the question:

```
.sidebarLink a:hover, .sidebarLink a:active {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebarLink:active:after {
  content: url('./chevron.svg');
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
}
```

Which appends some general styles that should apply on hover (which apply correctly), and an arrow image that **should** appear when the item is active. It does, correctly and as expected, when you click and hold a SidebarLink - however, when you actually release the click and it follows through to the destination URL, the `:active` stylings disappear, and the image follows suit - even though there is an active tab/menu item.

I've attempted using `NavLink` instead of `Link` along with the `activeClassName` property, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Is there a way to perhaps say, within the SidebarLink definition, if the route that is passed in matches the current location, add a particular class?

Comment: Did you try wrapping `SidebarGroup` in `withRouter(SidebarGroup)`? `activeClassName` should work after that.

Comment: Unfortunately, applying `withRouter` didn't seem to affect anything, and the entire application is wrapped in `BrowserRouter` so I don't think that's the issue

Comment: The right way to do this involves `activeClassName` properly working, so I don't think you should give up fixing it. Can you link to an example where I can modify the code?

Comment: I actually realized I was pulling `NavLink` from `ReactStrap` rather than `react-router-dom` - that allows the `to` and `activeClassName` properties to work as expected. `activeClassName` is being applied to *both* menu items rather than just the one actively tabbed to, but... progress! Thanks for the help! :)